# How to find out if an answer has been provided

Tags: discussion, notifications

How do I find out if someone has answered my question? I managed to post a question this morning and have now returned, and I am completely lost.

I have pushed every single button, link, etc. but have gotten nowhere. I think I checked the 'Notify me' box, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Is this a common thing? Is this why so many people ask a question and then are never seen again?

Comment: Um folks,  if the OP ( @user685555 )can't figure out how to find the answer on the main SO site, how are they likely to find the answers below here on MetaSO now that their question has been moved here?

Comment: +1 Chuck! lol especially moving it to meta means he/she may get confused while loggin in and linking the accounts =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you also click your username (user685555) on the top. You will goto your profile.

Here you will see all the questions you posted and details about them.
[image]

Comment: Many thanks, hopefully I will be ok now. I have to say that this site, although undoubtable excellent is not the easiest for absolute beginners to use. At least I have taken the first steps now. Thanks again.

Comment: @user stick around and it'll turn out great. Also, if you're wondering this is meta.stackoverflow.com, its a place to talk about stackoverflow. Your question was moved here.

Answer (score 1):

[How can I fix my ASP.NET Razor markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498714/asp-net-razor-syntax) Magic. Click on your https://stackoverflow.com/users/685555/user685555 (username) or StackExchange and then Inbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on your username at the top of the page - you should be able to see a list of all of your questions on this page, your profile page.

If it has answers the number in the shaded box captioned "answers" next to it will be more than 0.